# Checkbox appears unchecked, although it is checked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am quite new to jQuery, so my apologizes if there's something obvious I missed but... I just want to have a part of my form to be hidden when a user clicks a checkbox.

So, I wrote this small jQuery script:

```
$("#belonging_entire_world").toggle(function() {
            $("#access_for_friends, #access_for_groups").fadeOut();
        }, function(){ 
            $("#access_for_friends, #access_for_groups").fadeIn();
});
```

When I click the checkbox tagged with the id "belonging_entire_world", it DOES hide the part of the form I want (the part represented by #access_for_friends & #access_for_groups) and if I click again, it shows this part again BUT the checkbox "belonging_entire_world" that I checked always remains visually unchecked...

If I open firebug after the script has run, I see that my checkbox does have the checked=checked attribute ... still, it looks unchecked in the browser (in all browsers!)...

I tried to add, in the first function of the toggle function the following:

```
$("#belonging_entire_world").attr('checked', true);
```

but still ... it remains as if it was unchecked...

This is driving me crazy, I don't see another option that remove the jQuery code, I really don't get it ... I put below part of the view:

```
<div id="Belonging-Access-Control">
      <h2> Who will be able to see & access this? </h2>
      <div class="field" id="entire_world">
        <%= f.check_box(:entire_world) %>
        <%= f.label(:entire_world, "The entire world!") %>
      </div>

      <div class="field" id="access_for_friends">
        <%= f.check_box(:access_for_friends) %>
        <%= f.label(:access_for_friends, "My friends") %>
      </div>
```

and the HTML of the page, after I checked the checkbox (firebug output):

```
<div id="Belonging-Access-Control">
<h2> Who will be able to see &amp; access this? </h2>
<div id="entire_world" class="field">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="belonging[entire_world]">
<input id="belonging_entire_world" type="checkbox" value="1" name="belonging[entire_world]" checked="checked">
<label for="belonging_entire_world">The entire world!</label>
</div>
<div id="access_for_friends" class="field" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="belonging[access_for_friends]">
<input id="belonging_access_for_friends" type="checkbox" value="1" name="belonging[access_for_friends]">
<label for="belonging_access_for_friends">My friends</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Andrew: jquery version: 1.7.2

Comment: Are you sure that the id : belonging_entire_world $("#belonging_entire_world").attr('checked', true); refer to the checkbox id?

Comment: @Cygnus: I added the HTML source code of the page in the question (only the relevant part)

Comment: ok thanks... just wanted to clear this out ;-)..  still looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with using .toggle(). Would it be okay if you used this function?:

```
$("#belonging_entire_world").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#access_for_friends, #access_for_groups").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("#access_for_friends, #access_for_groups").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

You can switch the fades, if you want the opposite fading. This might be a better solution in case the checkbox starts out as "checked". So this code will hide/show the other divs based on the status of the checkbox, not what stage on toggling it's on.

Comment: THANKS !! ... It works when using click as you said! (I just had to inverse the fadeIn, fadeOut in your answer). I was desesperate, thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure why toggle is weird in this situation. But yeah, wasn't sure which way you wanted the fading, so there you go!

Answer (score -1):

.toggle() as it was mentioned works, however another way that I personally prefer is to check the state of the [checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

This way, you can chain different conditional events to show/hide the extra parts in the form.

Comment: I meant as it was mentioned by ianpgall